# phpmailer gmail emails go to spam

Tags: php, email

I know this question has been asked before but my issue is a bit different. I use the php mailer to send a bulk of mails in a loop to customers from the database. In the body of the mail when there's no html stuff like body = "hello" the emails get delivered to the normal inbox. However, when I use html tags in $mail->Body then the email goes to spam. The code I use:

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;  
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP 
        $mail->Host = 'someone';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers   
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication 
        $mail->Username = 'someemail.com';                 // SMTP username 
        $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password    
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           

        $mail->From = 'someemail.com';  
        $mail->FromName = 'Mailer'; 
        #$mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional   
        $mail->addAddress('someemail.com');
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('rr.jpg', 'logoimg', 'rr.jpg');
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('bottom.gif', 'bottomimg', 'bottom.gif');
        $mail->WordWrap = 100;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters    
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML   
        $username = "123";

        $mail->Subject = 'Welcome'; 
        $mail->Body = "Hello, welcome"
        $mail->AltBody = 'Welcome ';
        $mail->send()
```

The issue is only with gmail. All other major mail providers such as yahoo, hotmail and live are fine. The emails go to inbox. It may be because I use quite a lot of html, colors etc in the email. But I don't know why gmail moves the mail to spam simply because it looks like many other spam mails. Is there any solution?

Comment: Is the `from` address from the same domain as the server sending the mail? I have had gmail problems in the last weeks where the sender address domain did not match the server's domain...

Comment: well, yes it is. The from address is just an outlook email address and I am sending the emails from the same machine where the outlook is set up

Comment: Same machine that outlook is setup on != the server holding the mx/spf/txt records for the domain.  Send from the mail server for the domain under a valid account and it'll work.

Comment: There's not specific domain yet set up. I am using the localhost and the local IP to work on it